# How to make MVC5 AccountController talk to a legacy security dll

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have inherited a legacy framework dll with its own methods for logging in and seeing what "groups" a user belongs to. It's a pretty typical home grown security module. You talk to it via the legacy dll methods. It doesn't use or talk to any of the modern .Net authentication / authorization framework.

I created an MVC5 application and got a lot of boilerplate including `AccountController` and I totally think it's best to use all of it because that's "coding with the grain" and not "against the grain".

I want to make the *minimal* changes to the MVC project boilerplate code to have it get it's answers from the legacy dll. Once it has those authentication / authorization answers, I want it to carry on as if it got those answers from the .Net framework.

To use just the login scenario as an example,

Here is the given boilerplate method inside `AccountController`:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }

  //SignInStatus result = Login(model.Email, model.Password);

  // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
  // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
  var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
  switch (result)
  {
    case SignInStatus.Success:
      return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
      return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
      return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
      return View(model);
  }
}
```

and here is my routine to get a "similar enough to be mapped" answer from my legacy dll:

```cs
private SignInStatus Login(string userId, string password)
{
  string SoftwareLicenses = "blahblahblah";
  try
  {
    UserCredentials = UserProfileType.Login(userId, password, 0, SoftwareLicenses);
    return SignInStatus.Success;
  }
  catch (AtlasBusinessRuleException abrex)
  {
    switch (abrex.Message)
    {
      case "Invalid Login Name entered":
        return SignInStatus.Failure;
      case "Invalid Password entered":
        return SignInStatus.Failure;
      case "Your password has expired. Please change the password.":
        return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
      default:
        return SignInStatus.Failure;
    }

  }
}
```

See, if I just uncomment my call to my routine in the boilerplate routine, that is not enough to turn on all the .Net framework awareness that I'm logged in and who I am etc. I totally understand roles are different but right now I'll settle for just logging in and having the website act like I used it's code to do that.

**UPDATE**

This is probably going to have something to do with the `ApplicationUserManager` and the `ApplicationSignInManager` that it creates in the `IdentityConfig` file in `App_Start`.

[ASP.NET MVC and Identity 2.0: Understanding the Basics](http://johnatten.com/2014/04/20/asp-net-mvc-and-identity-2-0-understanding-the-basics/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a new methodology to arrive at the answer here. The way I arrived at the answer is more significant than the answer itself.

### Methodology For Discovering The Answer

[image]

1. Find the .Net Framework source code. In this case it was [`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/) and [`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin`](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/)
2. Find the classes that are the "black box" that I want to inter-operate with. In this case it was [`UserManager`](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs) and [`SignInManager`](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SignInManager.cs)
3. Find the entry "black box" method that I want to inter-operate with. In this case it was `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` which is called in `AccountController.Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)`
4. Copy the method from the source code and paste it into the boilerplate subclass. In this case it was `ApplicationSignInManager`. Turn the method into an override by changing the `virtual` keyword to `override`.
5. Locate and comment out any code that is incompatible with my back end dll or just won't work or is not applicable to my application. Don't over-comment or assume anything. Comment conservatively.
6. If functionality is required that can be provided by my back end dll, provide it using my back end dll.
7. If this "black box method" (which we have just made white box) calls any more dark methods, repeat steps 4 through 6 for that method as well, and so on, recursively. You can do this with or without debugging. I used debugging because that was easier than trusting my eyes to follow the code flow.

### Result of using this methodology

**ApplicationSignInManager.cs** (overrode 2 methods, commented out code that would break)

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using AACOMvc.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.Utilities;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;

namespace AAAMvc
{
  // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
  public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
  {
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
    {
      if (UserManager == null)
      {
        return SignInStatus.Failure;
      }
      var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName).WithCurrentCulture();
      if (user == null)
      {
        return SignInStatus.Failure;
      }
      //if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture())
      //{
      //  return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
      //}
      if (await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password).WithCurrentCulture())
      {
        //await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture();
        return await SignInOrTwoFactor(user, isPersistent).WithCurrentCulture();
      }
      //if (shouldLockout)
      //{
      //  // If lockout is requested, increment access failed count which might lock out the user
      //  await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture();
      //  if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture())
      //  {
      //    return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
      //  }
      //}
      return SignInStatus.Failure;
    }



    private async Task<SignInStatus> SignInOrTwoFactor(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
      var id = Convert.ToString(user.Id);
      //if (await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture()
      //    && (await UserManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture()).Count > 0
      //    && !await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(id).WithCurrentCulture())
      //{
      //  var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie);
      //  identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, id));
      //  AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
      //  return SignInStatus.RequiresVerification;
      //}
      await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, false).WithCurrentCulture();
      return SignInStatus.Success;
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
      return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }


  }
}
```

**ApplicationUserManager.cs** (overrode 4 methods, commented code that would break, and added my code to make it work the way of the legacy dll)

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using AACOMvc.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using HerculesBusinessModel;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Data.Entity.Utilities;

namespace AAAMvc
{
  // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
  public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
  {
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static UserCredentialsType UserCredentials
    {
      get
      {
        return (UserCredentialsType)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserProfile"];
      }
      set
      {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserProfile"] = value;
      }
    }

    public override async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
      if (user == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
      await Task.Delay(0);
      string SoftwareLicenses = "blahblahblah";
      try
      {
        UserCredentials = UserProfileType.Login(user.UserName, password, 0, SoftwareLicenses);
        return true;
      }
      catch (HerculesBusinessRuleException ex)
      {
      }
      return false;
    }

    public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user, string authenticationType)
    {
      //ThrowIfDisposed();
      if (user == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
      }
      const string IdentityProviderClaimType =
          "http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider";
      const string DefaultIdentityProviderClaimValue = "ASP.NET Identity";

      var id = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
      id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id, ClaimValueTypes.String));
      id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.UserName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
      id.AddClaim(new Claim(IdentityProviderClaimType, DefaultIdentityProviderClaimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String));
      if (SupportsUserRole)
      {
        IList<string> roles = await GetRolesAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture();
        foreach (string roleName in roles)
        {
          id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, roleName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
        }
      }
      if (SupportsUserClaim)
      {
        //id.AddClaims(await GetClaimsAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture());
      }
      return id;
    }

    ApplicationUser user;
    public override async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
      await Task.Delay(0);
      var profile = UserProfileType.FetchUserProfileForLogin(userName);
      if (profile != null)
      {
        user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
          UserName = profile.LoginName,
          Id = profile.Id.ToString()
        };
        foreach (decimal groupId in profile.UserGroups)
        {
          user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole() { UserId = profile.Id.ToString(), RoleId = groupId.ToString() });
        }
      }
      return user;
    }

    public override async Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(string userId)
    {
      ////ThrowIfDisposed();
      //var userRoleStore = GetUserRoleStore();
      //var user = await FindByIdAsync(userId).WithCurrentCulture();
      //if (user == null)
      //{
      //  throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.UserIdNotFound,
      //      userId));
      //}
      //return await userRoleStore.GetRolesAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
      await Task.Delay(0);
      return user.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).ToList();
    }
  }
}
```

### Conclusion

I was surprised and very pleased that a somewhat robotic process could yield the answer. But I was even more pleased at how using this process taught me more about a strange new namespace (`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`) than I could have learned in hours of reading or googling. It may not be perfect, but I can use the same process to improve what I have here.